# wpa-aes EAP-peap authentication problem

Tags: routing, router, security, authentication

I'm trying to connect ubiquity NanoStation M2 as Station/Router mode to a hotspot that I believe has WPA/AES security and EAP-PEAP for auth.
I have tested the username and password from my laptop and it works fine. Now I'm trying to connect to the same hotspot from around 700 meters away using my Nanostation M2. However here's the error that I got:

```
Feb 04 23:59:10 system: Start
Feb 4 23:59:10 syslogd started: BusyBox v1.11.2
Feb 4 23:59:11 dnsmasq[19961]: started, version 2.47 cachesize 150
Feb 4 23:59:11 dnsmasq[19961]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-I18N TFTP
Feb 4 23:59:11 dnsmasq[19961]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.1.2 -- 192.168.1.254, lease time 10m
Feb 4 23:59:11 dnsmasq[19961]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
Feb 4 23:59:11 dnsmasq[19961]: read /etc/hosts - 1 addresses
Feb 4 23:59:11 dropbear[19963]: Not backgrounding
Feb 4 23:59:11 wireless: ath0 Set Mode:Managed
Feb 4 23:59:11 wpa-supplicant: Trying to associate with 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0 (SSID='Testwifi' freq=2437 MHz)
Feb 4 23:59:11 wireless: ath0 Set Mode:Managed
Feb 4 23:59:11 wireless: ath0 Set Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Feb 4 23:59:11 wireless: ath0 New Access Point/Cell address:1C:6A:7A:A8:EF:A0
Feb 4 23:59:11 wpa-supplicant: Associated with 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0
Feb 4 23:59:11 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Feb 4 23:59:11 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
Feb 4 23:59:12 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Feb 4 23:59:14 wpa-supplicant: Authentication with 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0 timed out.
Feb 4 23:59:14 wireless: ath0 Sending disassoc to 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0. Reason: Station has left the basic service area and is disassociated (8).
Feb 4 23:59:14 wireless: ath0 New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated
Feb 4 23:59:14 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
Feb 4 23:59:16 wireless: ath0 Scan request completed
Feb 4 23:59:16 wpa-supplicant: Trying to associate with 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0 (SSID='Testwifi' freq=2437 MHz)
Feb 4 23:59:16 wireless: ath0 Set Mode:Managed
Feb 4 23:59:16 wireless: ath0 Set Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Feb 4 23:59:16 wireless: ath0 New Access Point/Cell address:1C:6A:7A:A8:EF:A0
Feb 4 23:59:16 wpa-supplicant: Associated with 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0
Feb 4 23:59:16 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Feb 4 23:59:16 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
Feb 4 23:59:16 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Feb 4 23:59:17 dnsmasq[19961]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) a0:f3:c1:b0:a0:09 
Feb 4 23:59:17 dnsmasq[19961]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.1.91 a0:f3:c1:b0:a0:09 
Feb 4 23:59:17 dnsmasq[19961]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.91 a0:f3:c1:b0:a0:09 
Feb 4 23:59:17 dnsmasq[19961]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.91 a0:f3:c1:b0:a0:09 WR720N
Feb 4 23:59:18 wpa-supplicant: Authentication with 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0 timed out.
Feb 4 23:59:18 wireless: ath0 Sending disassoc to 1c:6a:7a:a8:ef:a0. Reason: Station has left the basic service area and is disassociated (8).
Feb 4 23:59:18 wireless: ath0 New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated
Feb 4 23:59:18 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
Feb 4 23:59:21 wireless: ath0 Scan request completed
```

it repeats over and over again.
I have updated to the latest AirOs firmware.
Thanks for any help

Comment: This would appear to be the key point you need to investigate, "CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed."  Not having access to any of the authentication process from the device or your RADIUS server makes it impossible to provide an answer, we would just be guessing (wrong password, cert issue, etc)?

Comment: I See. what about this, sometimes it'll show this first:
    `Oct  2 04:50:30 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed`
    `Oct  2 04:50:31 wpa-supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys`
    `Oct  2 04:50:31 wireless: ath0     Received deauth from f4:ea:67:12:c6:75. Reason: Incorrect frame type or subtype received from unassociated station (7).`
    `Oct  2 04:50:31 wireless: ath0     New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated`

The incorrect frame type. Does it ring any bells or indicates anything?

thanks :)

Comment: I wouldn't waste time on anything after the EAP auth failure. If the auth fails, then any traffic afterwards will be invalid until it attempts to reconnect.